# How to specify TeamCity build agent linux user group

Tags: linux, continuous-integration, teamcity

On my CI server CentOS machine terminal when I do

```
groups teamcity
```

I see output `teamcity apache`. But in my command line build step script when I use `groups` command I see only `teamcity`. How can I specify build agent user group?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to restart build agent after adding teamcity to group `apache`.